# Tesseract in Apache server : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, tesseract, tess4j

I'm using Tesseract in my JSF web application.

when I was getting familiar with the Tesseract API as a simple java project , It worked without problems, then once I integrated it in my web project which uses apache tomcat 7 server, I get the following exception :

```
20:27:56.291 [http-apr-8090-exec-14] WARN net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs - C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\gsdll64.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\gsdll64.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1142)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1446)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1268)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1237)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.copyResources(LoadLibs.java:136)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.extractTessResources(LoadLibs.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.<clinit>(LoadLibs.java:59)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.PdfUtilities.<clinit>(PdfUtilities.java:207)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.java:314)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:214)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:198)
at Util.ReadFiles.OCR(ReadFiles.java:248)
at Util.ReadFiles.readImages(ReadFiles.java:184)
at Util.ReadFiles.dispatcher(ReadFiles.java:97)
at Util.ReadFiles.<init>(ReadFiles.java:71)
at Web.Controller.DocumentController.search(DocumentController.java:350)
at Web.Controller.DocumentController.getDocuments(DocumentController.java:780)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:46)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:43)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1276)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at Util.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:35)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here's my calling method :

```
/**
 * Reading PDF and images with Tesseract OCR
 * @param filePath
 * @return content
 */
public String OCR(String filePath)
{
    String content = null;

    File imageFile = new File(filePath);

    Tesseract ins = new Tesseract();
    ins.setDatapath("../tessdata");

    try {
        content = ins.doOCR(imageFile); // <-- Exception thrown from here

    } catch (TesseractException e) {

        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return content;
}
```

as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miX6g.png) , the dlls exist, and my web app is the only app using tesseract, so I don't really know which process is using these libraries ... any ideas please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem, instead of keeping the server running and just rebuilding my project, I have to restart the server every time because it was the server itself that didn't release the dlls after the first time tesseract was called.

hope this will help someone in the future

PS : I'm using IntellijIdea.